# Set a default value to a Combobox in php

Tags: php, combobox, default-value

I modify a code which gives a set of values as dropdown in a combobox. But I want to set a default value to the combobox while the drop down is there. This is my code. If you can help me I really appreciate your help. Thnks in advance.

//Add a drop down list of countries

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-9">
  <select class="select2" name="country" id="country" data-placeholder="Country" required style="width:100%;">
    <option value=""> Select </option>
    <?php foreach($this->countries as $pro){
      echo '<option value="'.$pro->id.'">'.$pro->country_name.'</option>'; 
    }
?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add the `selected` attribute to the option you want to make default.

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz, Yes I fixed it in that way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this Condition**

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-9">
  <select class="select2" name="country" id="country" data-placeholder="Country" required style="width:100%;">
    <option value=""> Select </option>
    <?php foreach($this->countries as $pro){
      echo '<option value="'.$pro->id.'" '.if($pro->country_name == "india"){.'selected'.}.'>'.$pro->country_name.'</option>'; 
    }
?>
  </select>
</div>
```